# PhoneGap/Cordova 2.2.0 Facebook plugin On IOS FB.init fail

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I'm Developing a PhoneGap 2.2.0/IOS app and need to use FaceBook plugin' i followed the install process as described in GIT, when i use the "simple" sample from the example folder
i get the device ready dialog that tells me to put my appID in place, i did that, then i press the OK and the app is thrown by IOS with this error:

```
'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'
```

and hear is my FB.init

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

                              try {
                              alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                              FB.init({ appId: "fb245065455620705", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
                              document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
                              } catch (e) {
                              alert(e);
                              }
                              }, false);
```

This is entries added to my plist file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.mdsitg.amisrael</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb245065455620705</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```
FB.init({ appId: "fb245065455620705", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
```

It should be:

```
FB.init({ appId: "245065455620705", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
```

Note, the "fb" should not be part of the App ID.

Comment: This was my first attempt, i removed it and still get the same result, do you know a good sample ready to use project for ios, im straggling this issue for 4 days now with no sucsess

Comment: as you can see i found my problem, and your remark was right, i didnt supply all the plist so you couldn't see all problems i head in the project, anyway you was right in what you told me

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was on my projectname.plist i was missing one of the elements required, i was skiping it in the when implementing the instructions
Thank you for trying to help, i now have a base IOS with PhoneGap/Cordova 2.2.0 with FaceBook plugin working, if any body need one ill be glad to give it

This is the source code of my plist that solved my problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>עמישראל</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>icon-1.png</string>
        <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon114.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon-1.png</string>
                <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
                <string>icon114.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mdsitg.amisrael</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.mdsitg.amisrael</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb245065455620705</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>245065455620705</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

if you need more help please ask me

Comment: please tell us, what element was skipped by you?

Comment: I am facing same problem please help me

Comment: Hi Im updating my answer to try and help you it its on IOS and my problem was miising few lines in the plist I'll put the plist code in the updated answer

Comment: @ShimonWiener Hey Shimon, would it be possible for you to post your bare bones project for us to use as a template, with maybe a little blurb on where the app id's etc need to be changed? I've personally been beating away at this for about 2-3 days and almost everything I come across is outdated and it would help me and others a great deal I'm sure!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding FacebookAppID key/value to your *-info.plist?

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ and click:

5: Configuring a new XCode Project.

Scroll down to: "Adding your Facebook App ID"

Essentially you need to find your projectname-info.plist and add a new key/value pair. The key will be FacebookAppID and the value will be your app id 245065455620705 (no FB in the front.)